# SWIFT: Changing view controllers with CMDeviceMotion

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, devicemotion

I am following this article: http://nshipster.com/cmdevicemotion/ On how to use CMDeviceMotion.

They named this part of the article: Keep It To Yourself

I made a viewcontroller with a identifier called: PromptViewController.

I get an error: Use of undeclared type 'PromptViewController' In the section:

```
 if let promptViewController = self?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PromptViewController") as? PromptViewController {`
```

Here is my full code:

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  upload_images


import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
@IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // get magnitude of vector via Pythagorean theorem
    func magnitudeFromAttitude(attitude: CMAttitude) -> Double {
        return sqrt(pow(attitude.roll, 2) + pow(attitude.yaw, 2) + pow(attitude.pitch, 2))
    }

    // initial configuration
    var initialAttitude = manager.deviceMotion!.attitude
    var showingPrompt = false

    // trigger values - a gap so there isn't a flicker zone
    let showPromptTrigger = 1.0
    let showAnswerTrigger = 0.8

    if manager.deviceMotionAvailable {
        manager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
            [weak self] (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: NSError?) in

            guard let data = data else { return }

            // translate the attitude
            data.attitude.multiplyByInverseOfAttitude(initialAttitude)

            // calculate magnitude of the change from our initial attitude
            let magnitude = magnitudeFromAttitude(data.attitude) ?? 0

            // show the prompt
            if !showingPrompt && magnitude > showPromptTrigger {
                if let promptViewController = self?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PromptViewController") as? PromptViewController {
                    showingPrompt = true

                    promptViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
                    self?.presentViewController(promptViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }

            // hide the prompt
            if showingPrompt && magnitude < showAnswerTrigger {
                showingPrompt = false
                self?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

}


@IBAction func selectPicture(sender: AnyObject) {

    let ImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    ImagePicker.delegate = self
    ImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary

    self.presentViewController(ImagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    image.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}



@IBAction func upload_request(sender: AnyObject) {
    UploadRequest()
}



func UploadRequest()
{
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.kaleidosblog.com/tutorial/upload.php")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()


    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    if (image.image == nil)
    {
        return
    }

    let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.image!)


    if(image_data == nil)
    {
        return
    }


    let body = NSMutableData()

    let fname = "test.png"
    let mimetype = "image/png"




    body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("hi\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



    body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(image_data!)
    body.appendData("\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)


    body.appendData("--\(boundary)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



    request.HTTPBody = body



    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()


    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (
        let data, let response, let error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        print(dataString)

    }

    task.resume()


}


func generateBoundaryString() -> String
{
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"
}
```

Here is an image of my code error:

[Image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpVuh.jpg)

Do you know how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't created a class `PromptViewController`

Comment: It doesn't work when I try to do that @Paulw11 could you please give me an example of a class I can make?

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't know why it isn't working. I have been trying all day.

Comment: They don't seem to have included that view controller source in the article.  It seems to be more some blocks of code that you can use in your own apps than a fully fledged tutorial with complete code.

Comment: @Paulw11 Do you know where I can get that?

Comment: @Paulw11 If you can't find it is there another article you know about it that teaches what I want? This was the only one I could find.

Comment: To be honest it looks like you need some more experience in the fundamentals of iOS programming.  Someone with experience would have no trouble using the code in that article to get going with Core Motion.  I don't want to sound mean, but you can't just expect Google to throw up working apps for you.