# SWIFT: What does the Error “Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)” mean?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, gyroscope

I got this error, and how can I solve this error? When I run the app it crashes. It gives that error, Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

The error is at the line: `let initialAttitude = manager.deviceMotion!.attitude`

```
// get magnitude of vector via Pythagorean theorem
        func magnitudeFromAttitude(attitude: CMAttitude) -> Double {
            return sqrt(pow(attitude.roll, 2) + pow(attitude.yaw, 2) + pow(attitude.pitch, 2))
        }

        // initial configuration
        let initialAttitude = manager.deviceMotion!.attitude //THIS IS THE LINE OF CODE WITH THE ERROR
        var showingPrompt = false

        // trigger values - a gap so there isn't a flicker zone
        let showPromptTrigger = 1.0
        let showAnswerTrigger = 0.8

        if manager.deviceMotionAvailable {
            manager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
                [weak self] (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: NSError?) in

                guard let data = data else { return }
```

Comment: Does `deviceMotion` really have a value at that point? What do you get if you print `manager.deviceMotion`? I have seen nil optionals causing this sometimes.

Comment: It has a value later in the code... @AndyIbanez

Comment: If I take away that part of the code I cannot have .attitude there...

Comment: It MUST have a non-nil value at the moment you are doing the force-unwrap. If there's a slight chance it won't, don't force unwrap.

Comment: @AndyIbanez It would really help if you could correct the code for me in an answer and if it works I will mark your answer correct. Thanks!

Comment: That would require you to post the entire code where this is happening, as it is not possible to know what happens to `deviceMotion` based on what we have now, and then we would be breaking the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable principle](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you print the value of `manager.deviceMotion` *before* you force-unwrap it, you will know whether it is nil or not and work from there.

Comment: It is hard to supply code; you need to make a decision.  What default value should `initialAttitude` have before you have a value from the device? 0?  Should it be an optional and therefore nil?

Comment: Here is the code: https://github.com/infinernet/Code/issues/1

Comment: Could you please help @AndyIbanez

Comment: There is more code @Paulw11

Comment: What we are trying to explain that is that at the point in time when your app tries to execute `let initialAttitude = manager.deviceMotion!.attitude` `manager.deviceMotion` is `nil`, so you *can't get its attitude*.  You need to decide how you want your app to behave when the attitude isn't available.  Noone else can decide.  You are going to have code that is something like `if let motion = manager.deviceMotion { let initialAttitude = motion.attitude ...} else { What happens? }` - you need to work out what that `else` is.

Comment: Could you please give me an example with it in the code? @Paulw11 Nothing is working for me...

Comment: Really, like I have asked you twice (three times with this), if you print the value (or do any other checks there) of `manager.deviceMotion` *before* you force unwrap it, it will tell us if it is nil and thus the cause of the problem. If it isn't, we can think of other possible causes. If the crash is a force unwrapped nil optional, you can use @Paulw11's advice to fix it. What you cannot do is throw us a bunch of code and expect us to fix it. That's something I could charge money for.

Comment: It isn't about code.  It is about *you* deciding what your app should do when `deviceMotion` isn't available.

Comment: What else could I use @Paulw11 ?

Comment: It printed nil
(lldb)

Comment: The problem seems to be the structure of your code.  You are trying to do everything in `viewDidLoad`, but your code requires you to have received at least one gyro update before you know what the initial attitude is.

Comment: What should I do about that? @AndyIbanez

Comment: @Paulw11 I am not the best at coding. Do you know where to put it?

Comment: @AndyIbanez What should I do with the nil?

Comment: Then @Paulw11's advice is sound. You need to decide how to gracefully handle that optional. Since it isn't guaranteed to have a value at that point, you need to decide what to do with it and what sort of default value it should have. Core Location has useful callbacks for this sort of stuff. You can use them to populate your variable and execute the code that required that altitude. Paul put it nicely; it's not about code, it's about the logic your code should perform when a value doesn't exist, and that's entirely up to you.

Comment: @AndyIbanez But I do not know what to put in the code... Could you please quickly correct my code. It will be quick for you and I don't understand it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you guys help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595784/swift-changing-view-controllers-with-cmdevicemotion @AndyIbanez

Comment: And could you please to @Paulw11 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595784/swift-changing-view-controllers-with-cmdevicemotion