# How can I have an image switch to another image?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimage

How can I have an image switch to another image when I move the device up and down?  If it is to complicated to explain can someone please link me to an article? I tried http://nshipster.com/cmdevicemotion/ but it did not work. I couldn't find anything else. Can you please help?

I tried

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  cheesetest
//
//  Created by Elia Baitel on 7/26/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 infinernet. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreMotion
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!


    let manager = CMMotionManager()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let manager = CMMotionManager()
        if manager.gyroAvailable {
            // ...
        }
        manager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.1
        manager.startGyroUpdates()
        let queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
        manager.startGyroUpdatesToQueue(queue) {
            (data, error) in
            // ...
        }

        // get magnitude of vector via Pythagorean theorem
        func magnitudeFromAttitude(attitude: CMAttitude) -> Double {
            return sqrt(pow(attitude.roll, 2) + pow(attitude.yaw, 2) + pow(attitude.pitch, 2))
        }

        // initial configuration
        var initialAttitude = manager.deviceMotion!.attitude
        var showingPrompt = false

        // trigger values - a gap so there isn't a flicker zone
        let showPromptTrigger = 1.0
        let showAnswerTrigger = 0.8

        if manager.deviceMotionAvailable {
            manager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
                [weak self] (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: NSError?) in

                guard let data = data else { return }

                // translate the attitude
                data.attitude.multiplyByInverseOfAttitude(initialAttitude)

                // calculate magnitude of the change from our initial attitude
                let magnitude = magnitudeFromAttitude(data.attitude) ?? 0

                // show the prompt
                if !showingPrompt && magnitude > showPromptTrigger {
                    if let promptViewController = self?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PromptViewController") as? PromptViewController {
                        showingPrompt = true

                        promptViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
                        self?.presentViewController(promptViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }

                // hide the prompt
                if showingPrompt && magnitude < showAnswerTrigger {
                    showingPrompt = false
                    self?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }






        // get magnitude of vector via Pythagorean theorem
           }}
```

But I got an error saying Use of undeclared type "PromptViewController"

Here is an image of that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpVuh.jpg

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: @DanielOrmeño The Keep It To Yourself section in  http://nshipster.com/cmdevicemotion/ I have had many problems with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595784/swift-changing-view-controllers-with-cmdevicemotion?noredirect=1#comment64595689_38595784 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603538/swift-what-does-the-error-thread-1exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-i386-invop-s   I couldn't solve any of the problems.

Comment: Sorry, I mean you should show your code and what you have attempted.

Comment: Ok I will edit that now. After I edit it I will tell you so you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: I updated it @DanielOrmeño Now you can help me... Thanks so much!

Comment: Ok, does your ViewController has an identifier "PromptViewController" in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes @DanielOrmeño It does http://imgur.com/ragYtNR

Comment: Where exactly are you declaring your PromptViewController Class? your initial image displays a file with that name but your storyboard ViewController is not mapped to a PromptViewController class

Comment: I added that: http://imgur.com/a/5AOyX But it still does not work. It gives me the error  '“Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)”' On the line '    var initialAttitude = manager.deviceMotion!.attitude'

Comment: That's a completely different error, I suggest you read up on optionals, you are force unwrapping an optional deviceMotion which is nill at the time of access.

Comment: @DanielOrmeño Could you please fix it for me? I was literally trying all day.

Comment: @DanielOrmeño I am completely lost on this...

Comment: Sorry I don't know enough about what your requirement is nor I have access to your whole code, I'd suggest going thought the documentation or posting a public repo with your code so we can help you further.

Comment: Here is a link to my full project... http://www.filedropper.com/cheesetest

Comment: I really appreciate all your help @DanielOrmeño